# Can the type of a function be constrained to certain promoted data constructors?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to wrap my head around [promoted data constructors](https://ghc.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.1/glasgow_exts.html#datatype-promotion). In particular I was wondering if they are useful in contexts that do not involve type families and GADT's. So I tried to think about whether they could be use to constraint the term level values that a certain function could take. For instance, would it be possible to define a function that accepts only list of all `True` terms. The following will not work, since `(->)` is a function from `Type` to `Type` and `'[ 'True]` has kind `[Bool]`:

```
allTrue :: '[ 'True] -> Int
allTrue = length
```

However I was wondering if one could make use of the promoted data constructor `'True` to define such a function. Furthermore, would such definition always require GADT's and/or type-families?

Comment: I think people forget to explicitly state the kind of `(->) :: Type -> Type -> Type` and treat it like a primitive, actually the kind has gotten progressively more complicated with representation polymorphism `forall {rep1 :: RuntimeRep} {rep2 :: RuntimeRep}. TYPE rep1 -> TYPE rep2 -> Type`. Then linear types replaced `(->)` with `FUN Many`. Now `FUN :: Multiplicity -> forall {rep1 :: RuntimeRep} {rep2 :: RuntimeRep}. TYPE rep1 -> TYPE rep2 -> Type`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your specific question: no, there is no type whose values are lists containing only `True`.  The promoted constructor `'True` is just another type, but because it's not of the kind `Type`, it doesn't have any values.

To answer your more general question: yes, there is a use of promoted type constructors even without type families and GADTs.  Phantom types are types with a type parameter that doesn't appear in its values at all.  You can use them to have the type system do some bookkeeping for you.  For example, suppose you want to keep track of whether you've escaped HTML in a `String`, to avoid injection attacks.  You can write this:

```
data IsEscaped = Escaped | NotEscaped

newtype UserText (e :: IsEscaped) = UserText { getUserText :: String }

fromRawUserText :: String -> UserText 'NotEscaped
fromRawUserText = UserText

escape :: UserText 'NotEscaped -> UserText 'Escaped
escape (UserText s) = UserText (escapeHTML s)
```

You can then export from this module the type `UserText`, and the functions `fromRawUserText`, `escape`, and `getUserText`, but *not* the `UserText` constructor.  Now you have a type that keeps track of whether it has been escaped or not.  It will be an error to call `escape` on a `String` that's already escaped, and also to pass a `UserText 'NotEscaped` to a function that's expecting a `UserText 'Escaped`.

You could accomplish the same thing with something like

```
data NotEscaped
data Escaped
data UserText a = ...
```

but you lose the type information of knowing that `UserText` is supposed to be instantiated with `Escaped` or `NotEscaped`.  So this is, essentially, untyped programming at the type level.  Promoted data constructors let you do typed programming at the type level.

Answer (score 5):

You can generally avoid GADTs using higher-rank types, though it will be much, much less convenient.

```
{-# language RankNTypes, FunctionalDependencies, FlexibleInstances, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import qualified Control.Category as C
import Data.Functor.Identity

newtype Same a b = Same {unSame :: forall f. f a -> f b}

coerceWith :: Same a b -> a -> b
coerceWith (Same f) = runIdentity . f . Identity

newtype Flip p a b = Flip {unFlip :: p b a}

refl :: Same a a
refl = Same id

sym :: Same a b -> Same b a
sym (Same f) = unFlip . f . Flip $ refl

trans :: Same a b -> Same b c -> Same a c
trans (Same f) (Same g) = Same (g . f)

instance C.Category Same where
  id = refl
  (.) = flip trans

-- Constraint-based sameness

-- The fundeps improve inference
class Sam a b | a -> b, b -> a where
  mas :: f a -> f b
instance Sam a a where
  mas = id

same :: Sam a b => Same a b
same = Same mas

newtype Gum a b = Gum
  { unGum :: forall r. (Sam a b => r) -> r }

withSame :: Same a b -> (Sam a b => r) -> r
withSame (Same s) = unGum $ s (Gum id)

symSam :: forall a b r pa pb. Sam a b => pa a -> pb b -> (Sam b a => r) -> r
symSam _ _ p = withSame (sym same :: Same b a) p

transSam :: forall a b c r pa pb pc. (Sam a b, Sam b c) => pa a -> pb b -> pc c -> (Sam a c => r) -> r
transSam _ _ _ p = withSame (trans (same :: Same a b) (same :: Same b c)) p
```

Comment: Cool second solution. There is also a pattern synonym that brings the `Sam a b` constraint of `Gum a b` by pattern matching:  pattern synonym `pattern S :: () => Sam a b => Gum a b; pattern S <- (s -> Dict) where S = Gum id` given `s :: Gum a b -> Dict (Sam a b)`.